# how to avoid to being identified as spam when using smtplib in python

Tags: python, smtp, spam

```
import smtplib

smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
smtp.connect('smtp.163.com', '25')


from_addr = 'XXX@163.com'
to_addr = 'XXX@qq.com'


smtp.login(from_addr, 'XXXX')



msg = ('From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\n'
% (from_addr, to_addr))

msg = msg + '''Subject: Test

Hi, I just test this format!!
Just python send mail test - -.'''

smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg)
smtp.quit()
```

I dont know why the message has been always classified as spam, I will appreciate for any advice for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because email deliverability questions aren't really programming questions. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam

Comment: Having said that, constructing a valid email message by pasting together strings is not very robust or elegant, and often results in invalid messages, especially if you don't know what a valid message looks like. Python comes with an `email` module; it is admittedly crude, but still much better than manually crafting a message from snippets.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and the work-around was to set a message ID:

```
from email.utils import make_msgid
msg['Message-ID'] = make_msgid()
```

It is just a clue, I do not know if this fix will fit for you.

Comment: There is still an error named smtplib.SMTPDataError(554, DT:SPM), but I still want to thank you.